# C++ Pointer Deep Copy

Tags: c++, pointers, deep-copy

I am trying to make a deep copy of a pointer to an array of integer, and am having trouble deciding what code is unnecessarily verbose and what is needed.

The pointer I am trying to copy is just a simple integer array.

```
int* vertexArray = new int[G->size()];
```

It contains the numbers 0 to size()-1 as its values. My first though was to make a new int* where equal to vertex array,

```
int* shortestTour = vertexArray
```

but I believe that will make the shortestTour change every time I permute the vertexArray. Is the only way to make a deep copy of this with a loop like this

```
for(int i=0; i<G->size(); i++){
    shortestTour[i] = vertexArray[i];
}
```

and then to run that loop every time I find a tour/path shorter than the current shortest?

EDIT: This is for a simple, brute force implementation of the travelling salesman problem.

Comment: Why not simply use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead?

Comment: You can as well use [`std::copy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) to do this. It's actually unclear what you're asking about.

Comment: Do you **need** a deep copy? Or sharing the data is enough?

Answer (score 20):

As you may have guessed, a deep copy is not copying the pointer (after all, a pointer is just an address that points to some memory location), but copying the memory that is being pointed by the pointer.

So, if you have

```
int* vertexArray = new int[G->size()];
```

a deep copy is

```
int* deepCopy = new int[G->size()];
for(size_t i = 0; i < G->size(); ++i)
    deepCopy[i] = vertexArray[i]; // copy the allocated memory
```

Of course, there are smarter and faster ways of copying the memory, like

```
std::memcpy(deepCopy, vertexArray, sizeof(int)*G->size()); // should be faster
```

A shallow copy is just copying the pointer, not the memory,

```
int* shallowCopy = vertexArray;
```

Any modifications you'll make will be reflected by both `shallowCopy` and `vertexArray` pointers, as both now point to the same memory chunk.

You should think whether you need a deep copy or not. If you just want to share data around, you probably don't. If the data must be "local", then probably you do.